# Remove new line from find command output

Tags: shell, terminal

I want to use the output of find command with one of my scripts, in one command.

My script accepts:

```
some-script --input file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt --output final.txt
```

I want to replace `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` with a `find command.

```
some-script --input `find ./txts/*/*.txt` --output final.txt
```

But this breaks, as there are new lines in the output of find command.

Comment: Try using -print0 argument find, that will print the result without the newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be adaptable to whatever shell script language you are using..

Example:

```
find . -type f | grep "\.cc" > ~/lolz.tmp
tr '\n' ' ' < ~/lolz.tmp
```

Your example:

```
find ./txts/*/*.txt > ~/lolz2.tmp
tr '\n' ' ' < ~/lolz2.tmp
```

Comment: Why use an extra temp file when you can just pipe ??

Comment: Of course you can pipe as well, all these tools support that

Comment: How about `tr -d '\n'`?

Answer (score 12):

Find can output a space-separated list of results without relying on other commands:

```
find . -name someFile -type f -printf "%p "
```

The above will find all files named "someFile" in the current directory or any sub-directories, and then print the results without line breaks.

For example, given this directory tree:

```
.../dir1/someFile.txt
.../dir1/dir2/someFile.txt
```

Running `find . -name '*.txt' -type f -printf "%p "` from dir1 will output:

```
someFile.txt ./dir2/someFile.txt
```

---

The arguments, options, and "actions" (i.e. -printf) passed to the above `find` command can be modified as follows:

- If you don't give the `-type f` option, `find` will report file system entries of all types named `someFile`. Further, `find`'s man page lists other parameters that can be given to `-type` that will cause `find` to search for directories only, or executable files only, or links only, etc...
- Change `-printf "%p "` to `-printf "%f "` to print file names sans path, or again, see `find`'s man page for other format specifications that `find`'s `printf` action accepts.
- Change `.` to some other directory path to search other directory trees.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the ls command instead of find command.
e.g. 
some-script --input `ls ./txts/*/*.txt` --output final.txt
ls output the files as ./txt/file1.txt ./txt/one/file2.txt .. etc

EDIT ---
You could use the find and replace the newline with space as follows :
`some-script --input find ./txts/*/*.txt | tr '\n' ' ' --output final.txt`

Comment: Don't know if ls will be supported elsewhere, also doesn't give exactly one space